# reset password link redirect to login page

Tags: login, password, wp-login-form

When we try to reset the password using link

```
www.example.com/wp-login.php?action=lostpassword
```

email is sent with some link like

```
www.example.com/wp-login.php?redirect_to=url?action=rp&key=Z6l5JdAyusl0CHAZZ4qH&login=fhd@gmail.com
```

but when we click on the link that is sent it will redirect us to login page url is some thing like this.

```
www.example.com//wp-login.php?redirect_to=url%3Faction%3Drp.
```

#### Summary:

In normal wordpress when ever we click on lost password link wordpress show us a text box where we need to provide either email/username and then we need to click on get new password link and word press create a url and email it to that user.
User then open their inbox and click on the url sent by the wordpress to create new passowrd. when we click on that wordpress generated rather then moving to create new password screen wordpress move me to login page that is the issue.

Comment: Please add a little more details. It's hard to understand your problem and what exactly you are trying to do.

Comment: Questions are meant to be references for later visitors as well. Please rework your questions spelling/punctuation/grammar/capitalization so it as as easy to read as possible. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I just found the answer:

```
www.example.com/wp-login.php?redirect_to=url?action=rp&key=XXXXX&login=XXX
```

contains the fragment `?redirect_to=url`. Some plugin you have installed seems to add this using `wp_login_url('url');`, which results in an incorrect formatting of the url. Used with `wp_login_url()` your problems should be fixed.